# How to query with wildcard in prequel?

Tags: scala, wildcard, prequel

In prequel, a lean library for JDBC-access with scala, the following statement works:

```
val stmt = "SELECT content FROM email WHERE to_email = '" + toEmail + "' AND subject LIKE 'Hi " + firstName + ", please activate your Account...' AND from_user_id IS NULL"
val activationRows = selectNewsDB(stmt)
```

while the one with '%foo%'-

```
val stmt = "SELECT content FROM email WHERE to_email = '" + toEmail + "' AND subject LIKE '%please activate%' AND from_user_id IS NULL"
```

fails with this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'p'
```

If I println the statement and copy/paste it to the mysql-console, it works fine too.

For completeness, this is the prequel-code, with newsDB being of type DatabaseConfig

```
  def selectNewsDB(stmt: String):Seq[String] ={
    newsDB.transaction { tx =>
      tx.select( stmt ) { r =>
         r.nextString.get
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: To use %, I have to take 2 of them:

```
  val stmt = "... subject LIKE '%%please activate%%' AND from_user_id IS NULL"
```